# Jquery to swap image on hover in a different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, swap

I want to perform an image swap when hovering over an area in an image map.  Here is the code:

```
<div class="menu">
<img src="images/menu/menu_0.gif" alt="Navigation Menu" width="400" height="600" usemap="#Map" class="nav">
<map name="Map" class="mainnav">
  <area class="one" shape="rect" coords="23,61,255,110" href="#about">
  <area class="two" shape="rect" coords="215,154,342,201" href="#skills">
  <area class="three" shape="rect" coords="110,257,320,300" href="#education">
  <area class="four" shape="rect" coords="117,381,342,423" href="#experience">
  <area class="five" shape="rect" coords="171,485,359,536" href="#portfolio">
</map>
</div>
```

when I mouse over the area ".one" ( or .two .three etc.) I want to swap the scource of the image in ".nav" to "menu_1.gif" (and menu_3.gif menu_4.gif respectively).  I tried a simple jquery swap but I cant figure out how to target a separate element for the swap within the same div (.nav image src).  All the image swaps I have found use "this" as a selector.

I started with this jquery:

```
jQuery(function(){
     $(".one").hover(
          function(){this.src = this.src.replace("_0","_1");},
          function(){this.src = this.src.replace("_1","_0");
     });
});
```

But everything I tried past that was just shooting in the dark and nothing worked as I don't know how to select the right element to change the source for the image.

Comment: Could you please show your jQuery code you tried?

Comment: edited to show the jquery I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hGEFh/1/)

**HTML**:

```
<div class="menu">
<img id="menu_img" src="images/menu/menu_0.gif" alt="Navigation Menu" width="400" height="600" usemap="#Map" class="nav" data-menu-src="images/menu/menu_0.gif">
<map name="Map" class="mainnav">
  <area class="one" shape="rect" coords="23,61,255,110" href="#about" data-menu-src="images/menu/menu_01.gif">
  <area class="two" shape="rect" coords="215,154,342,201" href="#skills" data-menu-src="images/menu/menu_02.gif">
  <area class="three" shape="rect" coords="110,257,320,300" href="#education" data-menu-src="images/menu/menu_03.gif">
  <area class="four" shape="rect" coords="117,381,342,423" href="#experience" data-menu-src="images/menu/menu_04.gif">
  <area class="five" shape="rect" coords="171,485,359,536" href="#portfolio" data-menu-src="images/menu/menu_05.gif">
</map>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
jQuery(function(){
    $("map.mainnav area")
      .on("mouseenter", function(){
        $("#menu_img").attr("src", $(this).data("menu-src"));
      })
      .on("mouseleave", function(){
        $("#menu_img").attr("src", $("#menu_img").data("menu-src"));
      });
});
```

As far as I recall, using "hover()" for this is deprecated.

Comment: Didn't seem to work, is there anything I need to alter when I plug it in?

Comment: Hm... works for me in Chrome & IE 10 (hovering the image and doodles change when over certain areas). Which one are you using?

Comment: Did you also add "data-menu-src" fields to img & area tags?

Comment: See the demo pls. Did you copy jQuery _and_ HTML?